# Вопрос в добавлении obj в three.js

Tags: объекты, three.js

я написал код:

```
var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader2();
var intergrateIntoScene = function ( object ) {
    scene.add( object );
};
loader.load( "js/1.obj", intergrateIntoScene );
```

вроде сработал и выдал в консоль:

object_group "Cylinder_Cylinder.001_" was defined without material! Assigning "defaultMaterial".
OBJLoader2.min.js:1 parseArrayBuffer: 54.0ms

Проблема в том, что объект не отображается и вопрос в том как сделать чтобы он отображался, как добавить материал к этому объекту и как изменять его размеры?

Спасибо!